# How to make a JavaFX object appear in FXML?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

In the controller class I have the following:

```
    final String SOURCE = "Source...";
    private Label sourceLabel = new Label(SOURCE);
```

In the FXML, I try to make this label appear by:

```
<Label fx:id="sourceLabel" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="44.0">
```

Why is the label in the FXML preview empty instead of appearing as specified, i.e.: writing out the string "Source..."? Is there something I don't get in the syntax or some additional housekeeping/technicality I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

In your controller write:

```
final String SOURCE = "Source...";

@FXML
private Label sourceLabel;

public void initialize() {
    sourceLabel.setText(SOURCE);
}
```

I.e., use the @FXML notation to link the controller sourceLabel reference to the Label defined by the sourceLabel fx:id in the FXML.  Use the initialize method to initialize the sourceLabel data.